# libcurl rtsp teardown while getting siganl

Tags: curl, signals, rtsp

I was writing the rtsp code using libcurl from https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/rtsp.html.

I wrote the signal handler to catch the Ctrl+C and teardown the curl/uri to close the session while playing.

I got the error message - " curl_easy_perform() failed: Failed initialization " but I had already initialized the curl in main function.

====== code section ========

`#include <stdlib.h>`

`#include <string.h>`

`#include <curl/curl.h>`

`#include <signal.h>`

`CURL *curl;`

`char *uri ;`

`static void rtsp_teardown(CURL *curl, const char *uri)`

`{`

    `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_RTSP_REQUEST, (long)CURL_RTSPREQ_TEARDOWN);`

   `curl_easy_perform(curl);`

`}`

`void sighand(int signo){`

    `switch(signo){`

         `case SIGQUIT:` 

              `rtsp_teardown(curl,uri);`

   `}`

`}`

`void signal(){`

        `struct sigaction actions;`

        `memset(&actions, 0, sizeof(actions));`

        `sigemptyset(&actions.sa_mask);`

        `actions.sa_flags = 0;`

        `actions.sa_handler = sighand;`

        `signal(SIGQUIT, sighand);`

`}`

`/*`

   `rtsp option,describe .. could be found from url above.`

`*/`

`int main()`

`{`

`/*`

   `initial variable could be found from url above`

`*/`

     `signal();`

     `curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);`

     `curl = curl_easy_init();`

     `if(curl != NULL) {`

           `rtsp_options(curl, uri);`

           `rtsp_describe(curl, uri);`

           `rtsp_setup(curl, uri, transport);`

           `rtsp_play(curl, uri, range);`

     `}`

     `return 0;`

`}`

========================

Answer (score 0):

Hmm by the looks of this code the the code should "fall through" so to speak, there is nothing that waits after rtsp_play() (unless you've something inside the routine that prevents return).
**SIGQUIT** is called after **Ctrl+\**, **Ctrl+C** sends **SIGINT** [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html)

Besides check the pointer for NULL it is ALWAYS a good practice (in signal the handler in this case to check if it is still a valid pointer).